# Cloud code from parse.com

Tags: python, parse-platform

I'm trying to use cloud code from parse.com but when I type "parse new" in the Terminal the following error occurs

```
parse new
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/usr/local/bin/parse/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
File "/usr/local/bin/parse/main.py", line 550, in main
File "/usr/local/bin/parse/main.py", line 281, in handle_new
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 71, in join
path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 48: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'd used cloud code for a test app earlier today and everything went smoothly, but when trying to set up cloud code for the new app the above happened.

Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong?

---

It seems its a problem is that the name of the directory I was in had an accent which caused problems. It works now!

Answer (score 2):

You can't write cloud code directly in parse cloud,

For that You have to install parse console

and Create Parse App in local/cloud directory.

parse new "Your_app_name"

enter your credentials
and it will generate app
in app there is CLOUD Folder -> Traverse Their ->in main.js Edit your code

and Finaly push by parse deploy command.

Comment: When it asks for a directory, where does it create the directory? Can we supply a path? For instance, could we supply a project directory in which to keep all our Cloud Code code?

Comment: I think I understand it just by doing it. ;) The "parse new" will create a subdirectory in whichever directory you are currently in. So if I'm in "~/MyProjects/Foo", doing the "parse new" and specifying a directory "bar" will create it in "~/MyProjects/Foo/bar". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

Use this command to generate a new app:

```
parse new "yourappnamehere"
```

It will create your parse app. If you want to use express use:

```
parse generate express
```